# Take (value from this week) - (value from the last week) PowerPivot Dax

Tags: date, dax, powerpivot

I have a pivot table made from PowerPivot which looks like this:

[image: Pivot table]

The table is filtered by week.

What I would like to do is:

```
(value PLANNED week n) + (value BackOrder week n-1)
```

and repeat the formula in all the table.

It will look like this :
[image: Pivot table]

So i try to do this using Calculated field, i try with this formula :

```
Planned(n)+BackOrder (n-1) =
SUM ( FactCommandes[PLANNED] )
    + (
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( FactCommandes[Backorder] );
            FILTER (
                ALL ( DimCalendrier[SemNr] );
                DimCalendrier[SemNr]
                    = MIN ( DimCalendrier[SemNr] ) - 1
            )
        )
    )
```

this gives me :
[image: Pivot Table]

As you see it work for the week 30 because there is BackOrder this week, but obviously it doesn't work for the next week.

I would be grateful if someone finds a solution.

Best regards,

Arnaud

Comment: What did you try so far? Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like you're after a [cumulative total](https://www.daxpatterns.com/cumulative-total/).

Comment: First , thanks a lot for helping me . I look for a solution with cumulative total thanks to the link of Alexis Olson. But i'm facing another problem , i have to re edit my post to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of getting this done. I would do this:

First, create a measure that combines backorder and planned orders:

```
Total Orders = SUM(FactCommandes[PLANNED]) + SUM(FactCommandes[Backorder])
```

Then, compute cumulative total:

```
Cumulative Orders = 
VAR Current_Week = MAX( DimCalendrier[SemNr] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE ( [Total Orders], 
              FILTER ( ALL ( DimCalendrier[SemNr] ), DimCalendrier[SemNr] <= Current_Week))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RADO it works great !!!  I just have to remove the VAR because powerpivot seem to do not accept variable. So It gives : Cumulative Orders =
  CALCULATE ( SUM(FactCommandes[DEMANDE&BACKORDER]);
              FILTER (ALL ( DimCalendrier[SemNr] );DimCalendrier[SemNr] <= MAX( DimCalendrier[SemNr]  ) )  )                                                                            Thanks again !